# Means within each group with more than 1 column of group indices

Tags: r, matrix, grouping, mean, sapply

I have a variable and I would like to obtain the means within each group where the group is listed for each observation in a column and I have many such columns. I would then like to associate the group means to the appropriate observation so that if I start with a matrix of m obs x n different groupings I obtain an m x n matrix of means. For example:

```
> var <- round(runif(10),digits=2)

> var
[1] 0.47 0.21 0.80 0.65 0.32 0.72 0.29 0.93 0.77 0.64
> groupings <- cbind(sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace=TRUE),
           sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace=TRUE),
           sample(c(1,2,3,5), 10, replace=TRUE))
> groupings
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    3    1    5
 [2,]    1    1    5
 [3,]    2    1    5
 [4,]    3    2    3
 [5,]    2    3    1
 [6,]    1    1    1
 [7,]    2    3    1
 [8,]    1    2    1
 [9,]    3    1    5
[10,]    1    3    2
```

I can obtain the means within each group separately with the following (for example)

```
> means.1 <- sapply(split(var, groupings[,1]), function(x) mean(x))
> means.2 <- sapply(split(var, groupings[,2]), function(x) mean(x))
> means.3 <- sapply(split(var, groupings[,3]), function(x) mean(x))

> means.1
    1     2     3 
0.625 0.470 0.630 
> means.2
    1         2         3 
0.5940000 0.7900000 0.4166667 
> means.3
    1      2      3      5 
0.5650 0.6400 0.6500 0.5625
```

But not only are these separate calls inefficient, they still don't get me what I want, which is the following

```
       [,1]      [,2]   [,3]
[1,]  0.630 0.5940000 0.5625
[2,]  0.625 0.5940000 0.5625
[3,]  0.470 0.5940000 0.5625
[4,]  0.630 0.7900000 0.6500
[5,]  0.470 0.4166667 0.5650
[6,]  0.625 0.5940000 0.5650
[7,]  0.470 0.4166667 0.5650
[8,]  0.625 0.7900000 0.5650
[9,]  0.630 0.5940000 0.5625
[10,] 0.625 0.4166667 0.6400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, you can use `apply`(because you already have a matrix) to loop through columns( with *Margin* set to 2) and pass the column to `ave` function as group variable, you can either explicitly specify *FUN* parameter to be mean or not specify it as *mean* is the default function used:

```
apply(groupings, 2, ave, x = var)  # pass the var as a named parameter since it is the 
                                   # parameter at the first position of ave function, if not
                                   # ave will treat the column as the first position parameter
                                   # which you don't want to

 #      [,1]      [,2]   [,3]
 #[1,] 0.630 0.5940000 0.5625
 #[2,] 0.625 0.5940000 0.5625
 #[3,] 0.470 0.5940000 0.5625
 #[4,] 0.630 0.7900000 0.6500
 #[5,] 0.470 0.4166667 0.5650
 #[6,] 0.625 0.5940000 0.5650
 #[7,] 0.470 0.4166667 0.5650
 #[8,] 0.625 0.7900000 0.5650
 #[9,] 0.630 0.5940000 0.5625
#[10,] 0.625 0.4166667 0.6400
```

Or with `dplyr`, you can use the `mutate_all()` function:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_all(as.data.frame(groupings), funs(ave(var, .)))

#      V1        V2     V3
#1  0.630 0.5940000 0.5625
#2  0.625 0.5940000 0.5625
#3  0.470 0.5940000 0.5625
#4  0.630 0.7900000 0.6500
#5  0.470 0.4166667 0.5650
#6  0.625 0.5940000 0.5650
#7  0.470 0.4166667 0.5650
#8  0.625 0.7900000 0.5650
#9  0.630 0.5940000 0.5625
#10 0.625 0.4166667 0.6400
```

Comment: Thanks!  @joel.wilson

Comment: Your concise code is superb! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1000)
var <- round(runif(10),digits=2)

groupings <- cbind(sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace=TRUE),
                     sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace=TRUE),
                     sample(c(1,2,3,5), 10, replace=TRUE), var)

df = data.frame(groupings)
df %>% 
  group_by(V1)%>% mutate(x1 =mean(var))%>% ungroup(V1) %>% 
  group_by(V2) %>% mutate(x2=mean(var)) %>% ungroup(V2) %>% 
  group_by(V3) %>% mutate(x3=mean(var)) %>% ungroup(V3)

#      V1    V2    V3   var        x1    x2    x3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      2     1     3  0.33 0.4775000 0.322 0.250
#2      3     3     1  0.76 0.6566667 0.470 0.750
#3      1     1     3  0.11 0.1333333 0.322 0.250
#4      3     1     5  0.69 0.6566667 0.322 0.635
#5      3     2     3  0.52 0.6566667 0.630 0.250
#6      1     3     3  0.07 0.1333333 0.470 0.250
#7      2     2     1  0.74 0.4775000 0.630 0.750
#8      2     3     5  0.58 0.4775000 0.470 0.635
#9      1     1     3  0.22 0.1333333 0.322 0.250
#10     2     1     2  0.26 0.4775000 0.322 0.260

# you can simply subset the columns
```

Comment: It is not recommended to do `data.frame(cbind` instead just use `data.frame(sample(c(...`

Comment: thanks @akrun i actually was continuing with OP's code. so performed data.frame() on it. I shall take note of it

Comment: Thank you. I probably should have mentioned that the real data has thousands of columns, unlike the toy example I created. In any case, I think I should familiarize myself with the dplyr package, as it appears to have some useful functions.

Comment: Absolutely useful package!! :) do accept one of the answers which performed the best on your data..

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method using `ave` along with `split` and `sapply`

```
sapply(split(groupings, rep(seq_len(ncol(groupings)), each=nrow(groupings))),
       function(x) ave(var, x, FUN=mean))
              1         2         3
 [1,] 0.4566667 0.5550000 0.3925000
 [2,] 0.6200000 0.5550000 0.3925000
 [3,] 0.4816667 0.5550000 0.3925000
 [4,] 0.4566667 0.5550000 0.6200000
 [5,] 0.4816667 0.5550000 0.4350000
 [6,] 0.4566667 0.5133333 0.6066667
 [7,] 0.4816667 0.0100000 0.4350000
 [8,] 0.4816667 0.5133333 0.3925000
 [9,] 0.4816667 0.5133333 0.6066667
[10,] 0.4816667 0.5550000 0.6066667
```

The entry to `sapply`, `split(groupings, rep(seq_len(ncol(groupings)), each=nrow(groupings)))` produces a list where each list item is a column of the matrix groupings. Each element of this list is fed to `sapply` which applies `ave` using the vector to group the results.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
var <- round(runif(10),digits=2)
groupings <- cbind(sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace=TRUE),
                   sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace=TRUE),
                   sample(c(1,2,3,5), 10, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: I also found your code useful. While Psidom's code can't be beat for efficiency, I found your code just as comprehensible. Thank you for your help.